# changing the keys of an array by reference php

Tags: php, arrays, ascii

I believe we could change the values of an array by reference in a foreach loop like this
`foreach ($arr as $key => &$value)`

I want to modify the keys in my case

```
$input = array(32 => 2, 99 => 4, 100 => 4);

foreach ($input as &$key => $value)
{
    $key = chr($key);  // I want to change the ascii character to a letter
}
```

I got an error saying, we cannot pass keys by reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to change the key to string?

Comment: @aldrin27 yes , that is correct, corresponding string literal of the ascii value

Comment: This is not a good idea at all: you are trying to change exactly the keys of the array you are currently iterating on. How do you expect the `foreach` loop to handle your attempt to modify the array structure it is currently working on?

Comment: Somethings just aren't meant to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616572/alternatives-to-pass-both-key-and-value-by-reference

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari thanks for the link , very useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if this works:

```
 foreach($input as $key => $val)
 {
   $key[] = [(string)$key => $val];
 }
 print_r($key);
```